# error: An entity must have at least 1 field annotated with @PrimaryKey

Tags: android

I am new to using room persistence and I have this error whenever I try running my code. It shows no error when editing but I get build error on gradle. It failed me that I had to copy paste codes but none seemed to work. The error is below

```
error: An entity must have at least 1 field annotated with @PrimaryKey
```

How do I work it out?
My code is below;

```
 package com.revosleap.dummy.DatabaseMov;

import android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Ignore;
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity

public class TodoListItem {
    @Ignore
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
     private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "time")
    private String time;

    @ColumnInfo(name="title")
    private String title;

    public TodoListItem(){

    }

    public TodoListItem(String time, String title) {
        this.time = time;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this entity class other than setting @ignore  on your id(primary key). If you believe error occurs because of this uninstall app from your device and reinstall

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't have primary key as **private** or **static**

Change `private int id;`  this line to

```
@PrimaryKey
public int id;
```

more details [Room entities](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data)

Comment: what if the create table command didn't define a primary key? what do you put in your entity?

Answer (score 3):

You should not use @Ignore with @PrimaryKey

> @Ignore annotation Ignores the marked element from Room's processing
>   logic.

Comment: Even if I remove @ignore the same problem still remains

Comment: did you increase version value inside @Database() in your RoomDatabase class?

Comment: are you sure you have just this one @Entity class? maybe elsewhere in your code you did declare another Entity class and it have the same condition

Comment: Its only this one. Am sure

Comment: can you edit the post and paste full stack trace error and your DAO and AppDatabase (RoomDatabase) class?

Comment: I dont have @Ignore annotation but still gives the same error. Any workaround?