# Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'. getting error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room

I am working on one project and it is not running successfully. I am getting following error due to Room database. Can anyone help ?

This is the exact error

```
Entity class must be annotated with @Entity - java.lang.Objecterror: An entity must have at least 1 field annotated with @PrimaryKey - java.lang.Objecterror: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ")": syntax error) - java.lang.ObjectD:\CheezyCodeRetrowithMVVM\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\aditya\cheezycoderetrowithmvvm\Db\QuoteDAO.java:17: error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: quote)
    public abstract java.lang.Object getQuotes(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                     ^D:\CheezyCodeRetrowithMVVM\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\aditya\cheezycoderetrowithmvvm\Db\QuoteDAO.java:11: error: com.aditya.cheezycoderetrowithmvvm.Db.QuoteDAO is part of com.aditya.cheezycoderetrowithmvvm.Db.QuoteDatabase but this entity is not in the database. Maybe you forgot to add com.aditya.cheezycoderetrofitdemo.Result to the entities section of the @Database?
    public abstract java.lang.Object addQuote(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

Comment: Does your entity have a `PrimaryKey`? Then you need to annotate it with one like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003179/error-an-entity-must-have-at-least-1-field-annotated-with-primarykey

Comment: yes it has the primary key

Comment: Can you please update your related  `Quote Entity` , `Quote Dao` & `Database` class in the question?